# Why are my photos not being saved in Shotwell?

Tags: shotwell

After cropping a picture in Shotwell, and rotating it, the original photograph has not been altered and is still the same. However when I go to the Shotwell "Library" they are shown as being cropped/rotated.

Why are they not being saved properly?

Answer (score 11):

Shotwell is a non-destructive photo editor, see http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/edit-nondestructive.html. If you want to share the altered photo then you will have to export it.

Comment: There's no Export option and *Save As* isn't saving my changes on a particular image although it does save changes on other images. This is with Shotwell 0.22 on Ubuntu 16.04. Probably a bug?

Answer (score 10):

`Shotwell` will not modify your original photographs. if you do some change in photographs like `crop` , `rotate` etc. and you want to save that then you have do Export it :

```
File ▸ Export ▸ Choose File Format  ▸ Choose Save Location
```

or
press :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> : For export image

**some other useful shortcut**

<kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>Delete</kbd>   : Remove from Library

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>I</kbd>  : Import from folder

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>O</kbd> : Crop Image

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd> : Adjust

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Y</kbd> :Red-eye

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>A</kbd> : Straighten

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>E</kbd> : Enhance

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> : Zoom In

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd> : Zoom out

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> : Show in File Manager